# C equivalent of C++ enum data for binary reading and manipulating

Tags: c++, c, enums, binary

trying to convert some C++ code into C, I'm working with binary data and need to use a C equivalent of this:

```
enum GssipFlags : uint16_t
    {
        SPARE0     = 1,
        SPARE1     = 2 * SPARE0,
        SPARE2     = 2 * SPARE1,
        SPARE3     = 2 * SPARE2,
        REQ_MSG    = 2 * SPARE3,
        DISCONNECT = 2 * REQ_MSG,
        CONNECT    = 2 * DISCONNECT,
        INVALID_DATA = 2 * CONNECT,
        CMD_REJECT = 2 * INVALID_DATA,
        HANDSHAKE  = 2 * CMD_REJECT,
        NAK_MSG    = 2 * HANDSHAKE,
        ACK_MSG    = 2 * NAK_MSG,
        ACK_REQ    = 2 * ACK_MSG,
        RESYNC     = 2 * ACK_REQ,
        MODE       = 2 * RESYNC,
        READY      = 2 * MODE
    };

    enum GssipMessageIDs : uint16_t
    {
        CCCCCCCC = 1,
        RECEIVER_ID_MSG = 2,
        BUFFER_BOX_STATUS_REQUEST_MSG = 3,
        SETUP_DATA_5031 = 4,
        WARNING_MSG = 5,
        TIME_TRANSFER = 6
    };

    enum GssipWarningMsgIDs : uint16_t
    {
        EXTERNAL_POWER_DISCONNECT = 17,
        SELF_TEST_OK = 8,
        AAAAA = 9,
        BBBBB = 10
    };
```

Everything I've tried hasnt worked. the main aspect of this I need is for everything to be uint16_t

Comment: These kinds of enums don't exist in C. You need to use explicit `uint16_t` values. Maybe `typedef uint16_t GssipFlags`, and a bunch of `#define`s.

Comment: Just drop the `: uint16_t`.  You can assign enums to uint16_t variables

Comment: Why do you need the numeric literal to have type `uint16_t`?

Comment: You can define the enumeration constants the same as in C++, although they will have type `int`. But the type of the enumeration is implementation-defined, so, if you want to have a `uint16_t` field in a structure or whatever, you need to use `uint16_t` explicitly. E.g., `struct foo { uint16_t Flags, MessageID, WarningMsgID; } = { ACK_MSG, RECEIVER_ID_MSG, SELF_TEST_OK };` should work.

Comment: If you truly need the constants themselves to have type `uint16_t`, you can define them using `enum` and then add macros such as `#define SPARE0 ((uint16_t) SPARE0)`. Macros are not replaced recursively, so this will just expand to `((uint16_t) SPARE0)`, and that will have the desired type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have one standard option and two potential options depending on your compiler and what "I'm working with binary data and need to use a C" means (memory usage?, speed?, etc):

- This has been already commented, the use of structs with the type you are looking for:

```
typedef struct {
    uint16_t SPARE0;
    ...
} GssipFlags_t;

GssipFlags_t a = {
    .SPARE0=1
    ...
};
```

- If you are trying to reduce the size of enums, take advantage of the compiler (if available) and use `-fshort-enums`.

> Allocate to an enum type only as many bytes as it needs for the declared range of possible values. Specifically, the enum type is equivalent to the smallest integer type that has enough room.

- `__attribute__((packed))`, in order to remove the padding added between members (which may do things slower due to the cost of accessing to unaligned data).
- If you don't mind about the size and your only concern is to compile C++11 code with a C compiler (which might produce the same output than adding `-fshort-enums`), just do:

```
enum GssipFlags {
    SPARE0     = 1
    ...
};
```

Items 2, 3 and 4 don't explicitly create members with `uint16_t` type, but if this is a XY problem, they provide different solutions depending on your real issue.